# how to get the value of the selected child[0] node in tree view

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the value of the selected child[0] node in TreeView?

```
 parent
|->Child  index[0]
   |->Sub Child 
       |->Child (for sub child)
 parent
|->Child  index[1]
   |->Sub Child 
       |->Child (for subchild)
```

`treeView1.SelectedNode` returns only parent node selected value but I want to access the child when I will be select the child node then I want to add the subfield after the selected node.

I want to get the value of the child then add the subfield.

how to add the sub child nodes into the tree

Comment: could you explain this a little more clearly please ?

Comment: You know, C# does not have a TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I fully understand you, but if all you need to do is get the selected value of any node in a treeview then the code below will work

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TreeNode n1;
        TreeNode n2;
        TreeNode n3;
        n1 = treeView1.Nodes.Add("A");
        n2 = n1.Nodes.Add("B");
        n3 = n2.Nodes.Add("C");
        this.treeView1.AfterSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterSelect);


    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
    }
```

Comment: By doing some testing, the selectedNode is filled in correctly when the node is left-clicked as opposed to right-clicked.